# How to use the contents of a text file(tab delimited format) to rename files in a folder?

Tags: c, windows, string, rename

I'm trying to make e-certificates to distribute for one of my college events. I used Photoshop to generate batch certificates with different names and roll nos. Now the files are named **core_01Data Set 1.jpg**, **core_02Data Set 2.jpg**, etc. In order to distribute them online, they need to renamed and sorted wrt the participant's name.
I have a .txt file with the participant names, their roll no and college name(in tab delimited format). I need to rename the files according to the content of the .txt file. I have tried my bit but couldn't go far. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char arr[3][20][40];
    int i=0;

    char final_name[19][50]={0};

    fp = fopen("./new/core.txt", "r");
    while(fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
    {
     while(fgetc(fp)!='\n' && i<20)
     {
        fscanf(fp,"%s%s%s", arr[0][i], arr[1][i], arr[2][i]);
        i++;
     }
    }

    i=1;
    while(i<20)
    {
        strcat(final_name[i-1], arr[0][i]);
        strcat(final_name[i-1], "_");
        strcat(final_name[i-1], arr[1][i]);
        strcat(final_name[i-1], "_");
        strcat(final_name[i-1], arr[2][i]);
        printf("%s\n", final_name[i-1]);
        i++;
    }
    char name[19][50]={0};
    char buf[19][50]={0};

    for(i=1; i<20; i++)
    {
        if(i<10)
        {
            sprintf(buf[i-1], "core_0%d_Data Set %d", i, i);
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(buf[i-1], "core_%d_Data Set %d", i, i);
        }

        printf("%s...\n", buf[i-1]);
        name[i-1]=buf[i-1];
    }

    i=0;
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir("./new/");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL )
        {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
            if (strcmp(dir->d_name, buf[i]) == 0)
            {
                rename(dir->d_name, final_name[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
}
```

LINK TO THE FILES : https://goo.gl/S6B3AB

Comment: Why even try to do this in C? Just use any simple scripting language. I'd suggest shell if not for Windows, but can still easily do this in things like python or perl (which exist for windows). I'm sure powershell will work too, though I'm not too familiar with that

Comment: I'm more familiar with C and C++, thus decided to go forward with them. Any help with the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use powershell if you want.  I think this would work.

```
$names = (gc core.txt)
$idx = 1

gci core*.jpg | %{
    $newname = $names[$idx++].trim().split("`t")[0] + ".jpg"
    ren $_ $newname
}
```

---

**Edit:** It's this

```
.trim().split("`t")[0]
```

part that splits each line of core.txt on tabs and returns the first element.  If you want the other columns included as well, try this:

```
$names = (gc core.txt)
$idx = 1

gci core*.jpg | %{
    $newname = ($names[$idx++].trim() -replace "`t+","-") + ".jpg"
    ren $_ $newname
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried Powershell for the first time and it worked. Can you also tell me how to add the **roll no** and **college name** to the renamed file? I'm a first timer in Powershell. 
Here's the latest screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B55XWlRkXur3VXIwNHJwVXYwU3c&authuser=0

Comment: @PeayushBhardwaj See the edit.  Instead of splitting on tabs, we now replace each instance of one or more consecutive tabs with a dash.  If you're teaching yourself PowerShell with this, some of the commands I used are shorthand aliases.  `gc` means `get-content`.  `gci` means `get-childitems`.  `%` means `foreach-item`.  `ren` means `rename-item`.  PowerShell's syntax is quite a bit different from C and C++, in that it frequently pipes the result of one command into the input of another command -- `get-childitems core*.jpg | foreach-item { do stuff }` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Only to give you a way to understand what You did wrong see the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char arr[3][20][40];
    int i=0;
    int numberOfNames = 0;

    fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");

    // read until fscanf can get 3 items from file considering tabs as space between strings
    while((fscanf(fp,"%s\t%s\t%s", arr[0][numberOfNames], arr[1][numberOfNames], arr[2][numberOfNames]) == 3) && (numberOfNames<20))
    {
        printf("%s %s %s\n", arr[0][numberOfNames], arr[1][numberOfNames], arr[2][numberOfNames]);
        numberOfNames++;
    }

    // this init only the first string with null termination
    char final_name[20][50]={0};
    //This init the whole matrix
    memset(final_name, 0, 1000);

    i=0;
    while(i<numberOfNames)
    {
        strcat(final_name[i], arr[0][i]);
        strcat(final_name[i], "_");
        strcat(final_name[i], arr[1][i]);
        strcat(final_name[i], "_");
        strcat(final_name[i], arr[2][i]);
        printf("%s\n", final_name[i]);
        i++;
    }

    char name[19][50]={0};
    char buf[19][50]={0};

    for(i=1; i<=numberOfNames; i++)
    {
        // Using %02d format you grants that the output is always with 2 digit at least and padded with 0
        sprintf(buf[i-1], "core_%02d_Data Set %d", i, i);

        printf("%s...\n", buf[i-1]);
        // sprintf is the way to copy a string into another string
        // You cannot simply name[i-1]=buf[i-1];
        sprintf(name[i-1],buf[i-1]);
        printf("%s\n", buf[i-1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use python if you want

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import string,os

f=open("in.txt")
a=f.readlines();

for x in a:
        x=x[:-1]
        r=string.split(x,",")
        os.rename(r[0],r[1])
```

Comment: its short and easy. (Y)

Comment: The question asked for an answer in C, not Python.

Comment: It was a suggestion to use Python and user did'nt say c is required. Moreover.. Approved answer is in powershell